# R Script trigger from outlook email

Tags: r, triggers, outlook

Is it possible to setup a trigger for an R Script so that once an email is received with a certain subject line the script automatically runs?

not sure if it's possible as R would have to constantly be monitoring my inbox for the trigger

thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: https://r-bar.net/r-scripts-mobile-device-email-triggers/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds possible to me.. check `library(RDCOMClient)`